# exporting results of powershell script to csv

Tags: powershell

I need some help, I have a small script which updates AD attributes from a .csv file however I want to export the results of the updates so I can check if its updated all users successfully or if there are any failures (i.e. it failed to find the user.).

Does anyone know how I can do this please?

This is the current script I have

```powershell
###UPDATE DEPARTMENT, DIVISION, JOB TITLE

$Users = Import-CSV C:\Users\Documents\CurrentWork\test.csv

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -property displayname | where {$_.displayname -eq $User.EmployeeFullName} | Set-ADUser -department $User.Department -Division $User.Division -Title $User.JobTitle
}

###UPDATE INFO ATTRIBUTE, DEPARTMENT NUMBER
$Users = Import-CSV C:\Users\Documents\CurrentWork\test.csv
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -property displayname | where {$_.displayname -eq $User.EmployeeFullName} | Set-ADUser -Replace @{info=$User.Service;departmentNumber=$User.'Cost Centre'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way to solve a problem like this is to create an empty obejct array, fill it with new custom objects, and then export the object array to csv.

In pseudo-code, it looks like this:

```
[array]$outputObjects = $null
foreach ($myVar in $myObjects) {
    [array]$outputObjects += [PSCustomObject]@{
        PropertyName1 = "Value1"
        PropertyName2 = "Value2"
    }
}

$outputObjects | Export-Csv -Path "C:\myFile.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

In your example, you could use this approach like this:

```
[array]$outputObjects = $null
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property DisplayName,Department,Division,Title,info,departmentNumber | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $User.EmployeeFullName}
    [array]$outputObjects += [PSCustomObject]@{
        UserPrincipalName = $adUser.UserPrincipalName
        DisplayName = $adUser.DisplayName
        Department = $adUser.Department
        Division = $adUser.Division
        Title = $adUser.Title
        info = $adUser.info
        departmentNumber = $adUser.departmentNumber
    }
}

$outputObjects | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Documents\CurrentWork\exportedADUserData.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Even faster, but only noticeable if you have a bigger amount of objects (~10'000+):

```
$outputObjects = foreach ($myVar in $myObjects) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PropertyName1 = "Value1"
        PropertyName2 = "Value2"
    }
}

$outputObjects | Export-Csv -Path "C:\myFile.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Don't do `[array]$outputObjects` and then add to it with `+=`. Instead do `$outputObjects = foreach(...){..}` and inside the loop, just output the object.

Comment: You are right, I tested and your version is around 3 times faster. Starts to get relevant when above around 10'000 objects, before it's barely noticeable. I'll edit my post